# Google Maps map can be loaded only once

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a page full of map triggers, when a user clicks on these links, I want to create the map with javascript. It works the first time around, but when I close the map and reopen it, the content is blank (except for the zoom, google logo, road/terrain dropdown). So it seems like it's 'almost' working. What am I doing wrong? I even tried to empty the content of map-canvas when I hide the map, but the issue persists. Thanks

Here is my html

```
<a href="#" class="btn cta map-trigger" data-lat="41.8911684" data-lng="12.507724100000019"> Show Map </a>
```

and here is my Javascript

```
var render_map = function( lat, lng, title ) {

    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');

    // options
    var args = {
        zoom        : 16,
        center      : new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        mapTypeId   : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    // create map               
    var map = new google.maps.Map( mapCanvas, args);

    // create marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: args.center,
      map: map,
      title: title
    });

    toggleMap();

}

var toggleMap = function(){
    if ($('body').hasClass('-show-map')) {
        mapHide();
    } else {
        mapShow();
    }; 
}

$('.map-trigger').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var lat = $(this).data('lat');
    var lng = $(this).data('lng');
    render_map(lat, lng);
});
```

Comment: `mapShow` is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around your samples this work :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #map-canvas {
        width: 500px;
        height: 400px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
         <a href="#" class="btn cta map-trigger" data-lat="41.8911684" data-lng="12.507724100000019"> Show Map1 </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#" class="btn cta map-trigger" data-lat="41.8911684" data-lng="12.607724100000019"> Show Map2 </a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#" class="btn cta map-trigger" data-lat="41.8911684" data-lng="12.707724100000019"> Show Map1 </a>
    </div>
    <script>
        var render_map = function( lat, lng, title ) {

            var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');

            // options
            var args = {
                zoom        : 16,
                center      : new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                mapTypeId   : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            // create map               
            var map = new google.maps.Map( mapCanvas, args);

            // create marker
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: args.center,
              map: map,
              title: title
            });

            toggleMap();

        }

        var toggleMap = function(){
            if ($('body').hasClass('-show-map')) {
                mapHide();
            } else {
                mapShow();
            }; 
        }

        $('.map-trigger').on('click', function(event) {

            event.preventDefault(); 
            var lat = $(this).data('lat');
            var lng = $(this).data('lng');
            render_map(lat, lng);
        });
    </script>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, yes the code works by itself... maybe some css? I'll keep searching, thanks for your help. I found the strangest behaviour, so that if i do inspect element (basically resizing the page) then the map appears!

Comment: If this is useful for you please rate the answer

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't know why this was needed in my case, but I had to resize and recenter the map each time I called it, using this snippet

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
   google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
   map.setCenter(args.center);
});
```